# _block_type_is_valid(phead- nblockuse) when erasing data from a vector of shared_ptr

Tags: c++, vector, shared-ptr, erase

It's my first time posting so I do apologize if I've messed up in anyway or made anything more difficult than it should be.

Here's my issue:
I'm trying to erase data from a vector of `boost::shared_ptr` nodes, nodes being a class.
In one part of my code, erasing an element from a vector known as openList works fine.
In another part of my code, erasing an element from a vector known as movingObjectsList, doesn't want to work. It gives prompts me with _block_type_is_valid(phead- nblockuse).

I've tried `clear()`, `popback()` and `erase()` and all of them cause the same problem. I can add what I like to `movingObjectsList` without any errors and swap the data it holds with other vectors, but I'm unable to delete any of the data.

I think I've ruled out it being an issue with the node destructor because I have the same issue when I use Ints instead of nodes, and also the `openList` is able to erase elements.

This is how it's declared in the header.

```
vector<boost::shared_ptr <node>> movingObjectsList;
```

This is the relevant code in the cpp

```
grid::grid()  
{
    movingObjectsList = vector<boost::shared_ptr<node>>();
}

void grid::createGrid(){
    boost::shared_ptr<node> movingObject = boost::shared_ptr<node> (&nodes[8][8]);
    movingObjectsList.push_back(movingObject);
}

void grid::movingObjects()
{
    movingObjectsList.erase(movingObjectsList.begin());
}
```

This is the simplest form I've cut it down to, only concerning movingObjectsList. 
Without the erase function, it works fine.

Comment: What is `nodes`? You do know that if the reference counter of a `shared_ptr` reaches zero the contained pointer will be deleted?

Comment: oops, sorry. node nodes[height][width]; It's my 2d array of nodes

Comment: Consider using `std::shared_pointer` instead, also take a look at `auto`. Be thankful your Undefined Behavior was caught by a debug assertion of delete.

Comment: how big is your nodes-array? Are the constants `height` and `width` by chance 8 or smaller? In that case you have UB even before the shared_pointer gets involved.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help and explanations :)

Comment: @Deduplicator I know the question has been solved, but I'm curious now. Why would I get UB for having an array smaller than 8?

Comment: Because the only pointer you may calculate point to an object, a subobject (arrays and structs) or just past an object. Any others invoke Undefined Behavior because the standard says so. This allows inter alia bounds-checking, segmentation, page-level protections and virtual memory. That even applies for node nodes[8][8], because then &nodes[8][8] would be 8 nodes after the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, mistake in what a shared pointer does.

A Shared pointer takes full ownership of a pointer. When that pointer goes out of scope, it'll delete that pointer.

You are inializsing the nodes as an `node [8][]`. Your pointer is an address in this 2D array! When you need to call delete (which'll get called when your shared_ptr goes out of scope i.e. whenever you remove elements from the vector), you are essentially calling `delete nodes[i][j]`, which you'd expect to barf.

Just use references in this case (Node&), which will be perfectly valid and work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

As answer I reiterate what I said in my comment: When the reference counter of a shared_ptr reaches zero the contained pointer will be deleted. This means that it will basically be the same as `delete &nodes[8][8]`. As it's not allocated with `new`, you will experience [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: I apologise, I don't fully understand. I get the same error if I insert more nodes into the vector and only delete one of them, would the contained pointer still reach zero in that situation?

Comment: If you create a new shared_pointer using a raw pointer, it does not know about any other shared_pointers you already have owning that, which is a bug.

Comment: @RagedMilkMan Yes, as you create *different* shared pointers. And if you make them all point to the same thing it's even worse.